# MutationObserver on nodelist

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I have some html with four section:

```
<section class="section"><div class="button"></div></div>
<section class="section"><div class="button"></div></div>
<section class="section"><div class="button"></div></div>
<section class="section"><div class="button"></div></div>
```

Inside of this section there is a div.button class, when the user clicks on it, the section gets expanded, covering the entire page (all the element inside become visible), and receives the class 'is-expanded'

Now i set a MutationObserver on those nodes (with class 'section'):

utilities.js

```
class Observer{
  constructor(targetClass,buttonHandler){
    this.targetClass = targetClass;
  }
  initObserver(){
    let self = this;
    const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
          if(mutation.target.classList.contains(self.targetClass)){
          let menuButton = Array.from(mutation.target.children).find(function(el){
            return el.classList.contains('menu-heading')
          })
          self.buttonHandler.disable(menuButton)
          console.log(menuButton)
      }
      else if(!mutation.target.classList.contains(self.targetClass)){
        let menuButton = Array.from(mutation.target.children).find(function(el){
          return el.classList.contains('menu-heading')
        })
        self.buttonHandler.enable(menuButton)

      }
        })
      }
      return observer
  }
}
```

main.js

```
    const observer = new utilities.Observer(expandedClass).initObserver()
const sections = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.section'));

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
  sections.forEach(function(section){
    observer.observe(section,{attributes:true})
  })
})
```

I'm new to mutation observe api, could be this a good use of it? even in terms of performance (instead of use addEventListener on click etc)

thanks

**EDIT** 
I update the code, for now what i want is that if section has the class expanded, the children button (with class .menu-heading) get the css style pointerEvents set to none, to auto if not has the target class. the enable function from buttonhandler class do the job

Comment: What is `sections`?

Comment: sorry, i edited the questions

Comment: Remove `new` in main.js and fix your indentation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to do this with a mutation observer? If your own code is handling the click, can't that same code update the buttons directly? MutationObservers are generally more for detecting changes performed by code that you can't directly control.

Comment: ok your right, I'm only experimenting, with only listener there is more less code